Adding current limiting to a buck voltage converter (MT2499) with INA213 and TL431 comparator
I am designing the power supply section for a circuit that will be mounted on a sensor node up a pole. I have chosen sealed lead acid batteries for solar backup power, and the circuit will also be connected to grid power.
There is an AC to DC converter in the design (HLK15M15C) that outputs 15V. To charge the battery, I selected the MT2499A IC because I’m using it elsewhere in the circuit, though I'm open to swapping it for a better IC. It is a generic 3A buck converter. The MT2499A will be configured to output around 14.2V.
To prevent the battery from drawing too much current when it’s empty, I want to have some current limiting at the output. I’m aiming for a CC/CV charging process. I’ve explored current limiting with transistors and shunts, but voltage drops make it difficult to possibly maintain 14.2V at the output. I also considered adding just a current limiter after the 15V and charge the circuit, but inconsistencies in voltage (e.g., possibility of reaching 14.6V) could compromise the battery’s longevity.
My current solution is to add a second feedback signal to the buck converter's feedback pin. This way, I can implement current limiting without losing voltage. I have seen similar approaches discussed in videos and forums.
I plan to integrate an INA213 to sense current. Once the current exceeds the threshold, I want to send a signal to the feedback pin. For simplicity, I intend to use a TL431 comparator, which compares the input to its internal 2.5V reference.
The INA213 is a current sense amplifier with a gain of 50. The voltage drop across the shunt gets amplified by the INA213, once this exceeds the 2.5V threshold, the TL431 will trigger. This will turn on the optocoupler, and the optocoupler’s output will use a voltage divider to reduce the supply voltage to a level the feedback pin can handle. The goal is to ensure the voltage is high enough to bias the diode (exceeding the MT2499 feedback voltage by at least 0.7V).

As said, this is just the power section of the PCB, there are other items already in the design and on the same PCB. I can't order the components right now and test them separately.
My questions/concerns:
Is there any reason this approach wouldn't work with the MT2499A?
Will the TL431 work correctly when there’s an optocoupler LED in its path?
What disturbances or surprises could the optocoupler introduce on the voltage divider?
I’m open to alternative suggestions or IC recommendations, as I’ve invested significant time in this design but am not attached to it :)

I am afraid this won't work: you want to add another loop on top of the existing one via the FB pin. If you want to implement constant-current (CC) constant-voltage (CV) type of regulation, you have to find a switcher which lets you pull the CV error amplifier down via an ORing configuration with an added CC error amplifier. For a buck converter, have a look at this TSC101 which is a hi-side sensor. An advice, stay away from parts like this MT2499A in which you only have specs at 25 °C and no characterization curves at all!

I personally would consider alternative charging ICs.
Since you mentioned openness to alternatives, there are dedicated battery charging ICs designed specifically for SLA batteries, which might simplify your design:
TI’s BQ24450 or MCP73871 from Microchip: These ICs are designed for SLA battery charging with built-in CC/CV modes and programmable charging parameters. They simplify charging management and can directly handle the transition between phases without requiring additional external control circuitry.
LM25117: If you still prefer to stay with a more general-purpose buck converter, the LM25117 is a buck controller with integrated current limiting and feedback options.
(Edit by OP) CN3768: Dedicated lead acid charging IC that is based on SMPS approach. It also has the needed CC current setting capability. This would be more efficient than the other mentioned charging IC's as those are linear and this is a switch mode one.

I wanted to minimize components and complexity, so I turned to alternatives other than these suggested. I have selected CN3768.
It is made for lead acid batteries and has a means to set current limit. Also it is very simple to use.

I would not use an optocoupler. I would start with something like this:

However, I am afraid that it will be necessary to add a compensator for stable operation.
Q1 is simply an inverting amplifier. There is no reason to make it a high increment. Approximately unity gain can be achieved if the collector and emitter resistors are the same. So R1 should be equal to yours R2 || R3 || R36.
In steady state, FB equal to 0.9V. Neglecting the current consumed by the MT2499A FB pin, the collector current through R2 || R3 || R36 leads to a voltage drop of 0.9V. Since we chose R1 to be the same, this means that the voltage drop across it will be approximately the same (since the collector and emitter currents are almost the same).
It follows that the voltage drop on R2 will be close to: 0.9 + 0.7 = 1.6 (V). By choosing a current through the cathode of U1 of 1mA, we can ignore the base current. Then R2 will be: 1.6 / 1mA = 1.6k.

TLDR;
It will not work.
First, the output voltage of the regulator will never reach 14.8 VDC due to the internally-limited duty cycle, 92%. So, for 15 VDC input, the max output voltage could be 13.8 VDC at best (i.e. neglecting all the losses due to the parasitic elements).
Second, and more importantly, some issues appear to be going to rise even from the start up. Your current sense amplifier will never kick in, apparently, and the inductor's core will probably saturate and this also may result in total destruction of the regulator. I tried to explain below.
Your implementation may work for the applications that don't involve any battery charging. But still may lead to some strange behaviour.
It's best to use a dedicated charger IC. Many ICs are readily available in the market. They have independent voltage and current loops, also they are optimised for longer life of the battery.

Let's assume that the battery has a voltage of 11.6 VDC initially and is connected to the output and the 15 VDC input is applied to the regulator.

The IC will try to turn the high-side switch on but it may fail because the bootstrap capacitor, C18 (used as a floating supply to drive the high-side switch at start up and throughout the normal operation), will have an initial voltage of 15 - 11.6 = 3.4 VDC (Ideally, the bootstrap capacitor could have charged up thanks to the empty, large enough, and therefore shorted output capacitor). If this is high enough then the high-switch will be turned on. If it is not then the IC may turn it off and turn the low-side switch on after some time as part of a stop-restart process (if there's any) and then turn it off again (1). But there's still a possibility of that the circuit may not even start up.
Following the turn-on of the high-side switch, the IC will fire up its internal soft-start which means increasing the internal reference voltage up to ~0.93 VDC gradually in 1 ms.

And this is where the shtf.

Because the feedback voltage is already 0.76 VDC and the ref voltage is going to be way too low due to the soft-start, the IC will quite possibly stop switching (turn the high-side switch off) immediately as a response from the voltage loop. And then it'll turn the low-side switch on after a non-zero dead time.
The IC will probably keep the low-side switch on until the end of the switching period because of the constant high voltage at the FB node, then turn it off. Whilst the high-side switch was on, the inductor voltage was VL = 15 - 11.6 = 3.4 VDC (SW node +, output/battery node –) and the duration was quite possibly too low (presumably a few hundreds of nanoseconds, not much higher than the minimum on-time given in the datasheet). Whilst the low-side switch was on, the inductor voltage was 11.6 VDC and the duration would be much longer. This means a volt-second imbalance which leads to the failure of de-magnetisation of the core.
Turning the low-side switch off leads to the inductor's flyback action (note that the battery, the inductor, the low-side switch, and the body diode of the high-side switch form a boost regulator). So the SW node voltage will jump, and once it gets high enough the high-side switch body diode will clamp the SW node voltage to input voltage (~15 VDC). There could be a high clamping current through it, let alone the backdriven 15V source. Although this happens during the dead time only which is a few nanoseconds, there still must be a diode to block the flow of the current back to the 15V source. But let's assume nothing bad happens here.
Then the high-side switch will be turned on again. The internal ref voltage must have increased, but still less than 0.76 VDC. So the IC will stop switching again and the things above repeat.

So, as the things above repeat, the inductor's core magnetisation, and therefore the magnetisation current, will get higher and higher and the core will quite possibly end up with saturation even before the soft start period.
The average current flowing through your 0.05 Ω shunt resistor will be negative (i.e. not to the battery, but from the battery) and increasing in amplitude throughout the entire soft start period so your current limiter will never kick in and stop the process.
Not to mention the gradually-increasing amplitude of the current flowing through the low-side switch which may kill the IC within a very short time because of the lack of low-side switch current limiting.

(1) Note that the IC may not turn the low-side on straight away but this does not change the overall result.
